# How do I know if my system is vulnerable to the ShockShell vulnerability?

Tags: bash, security

The recently discovered ShockShell vulnerability affects many Linux and Mac systems, because they are using the vulnerable BASH shell.

How do I know if I am vulnerable to this attack and how do I protect myself from it?

Answer (score -1):

The ShockShell vulnerability affects many systems.

### Is my system affected?

If you want to check if your system is affected, run the following command inside a terminal window **running bash**. Ubuntu's `gnome-terminal` runs `bash` by default (to see if you are running `bash`, then run `echo $SHELL`, and if it echoes `bash` then you run `bash`) :

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo hello'
```

If your system is vulnerable, then you will see this:

```
vulnerable

hello
```

If it is not vulnerable you will see this:

```
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt

bash: error importing function definition for 'x'

hello
```

### How do I protect myself?

Programmers have quickly released patches for this vulnerability, so make sure that you have the latest versions of all the packages in your system installed:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will upgrade your bash version to the latest, patched one and you should be safe.

### Why is this vulnerability serious?

This vulnerability is said by some to be more serious than the HeartBleed vulnerability because it allows remote execution of commands through bash to the infected systems.

Comment: /me adds this to the list of reasons to run zsh

Comment: This is not entirely true. The patch is not quite good enough yet, your system is still vulnerable. You can test with `env X='() { (a)=>\' bash -c "echo echo vuln"; [[ "$(cat echo)" == "vuln" ]] && echo "still vulnerable :("`. See also [here](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2014-7169). Also, `echo $SHELL` does not print the shell you're running, it just prints your default and `gnome-terminal` does not run any shell by default, that depends on your user's settings and is completely independent of the terminal.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen makes no difference as long as bash is installed on your system.